# Symfony Validate Multiple Entities and Related Entities

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine, entity

Using only the Symfony validator (no forms !), I am trying to figure out how I can validate multiple entities or (sub / related) entities and returning the errors in one array / object.

**E.G.:**

Lets say that I have 2 different user entities that I would like to validate, using the same validation group.

Using the [validator api docs](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator.html) I could do this as follows:

```
$user1 = ... //first user
$user2 = ... //second user
$errors = [];

$error = $validator->validate($user1, null, ['create']);
if(count($error) > 0)
{
    $errors['user1'] = $error;
}

$error = $validator->validate($user2, null, ['create']);
if(count($error) > 0)
{
    $errors['user2'] = $error;
}

if(count($errors) > 0 )
{
   // handle errors
}
```

This works however I am wondering if there is a build in way to do so ?
Like passing the existing errors to the validator, or passing an array of entities to the validator.

The same questions arise when I want to validate an entity with its relation.

**E.G.:**

Lets say that I have a Company entity which has a one to many relation with a User entity.

When creating a new Company I also create a new User.

```
$company = new Company();
$company->set...

$user = new User();
$user->set...

$company->addUser($user);

$validator->validate ...
```

Again I would like to validate this Company and the User. I could do it in a similar way as stated before. But again, the question arises, is there a build in way to pass in the existing errors or let the validator validate the related entity(ies) aswel (maybe with the validation groups ?)

Googling this issue gives me barely any decent results, so I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Or should I implement such logic myself (this is not a problem), I just want to prevent to rewrite such logic if it already exists.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can try to add validation groups for the case you are having. Fields from multiple Entities can be of one validation group, and you validate the "mother" entity

Comment: Ok is what I though should be possible, how about multiple (non related) entities ?

Comment: for collections on entities use @Valid: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

Comment: Awesome one for relations, now I only need to find if I need to implement custom logic to validate an array of Entities (example 1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want validate related entities use `@Valid` annotation.

If you want validate array of entities in one shot, one solution could be another class holding collection with this array and `@Valid` annotation. The point is that you not need form to validate object and also you not need doctrine entity. Just plain old PHP object with validation annotation.

If another object class is to much for you, it is possible to create constraints on the fly and pass to validator service with collection. In [How to Validate Raw Values (Scalar Values and Arrays)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html) chapter of Symfony Documentation you find a details (second example).